# Android Studio bug? Some Images in assets appear upside down

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio 2.3
Build #AI-162.3764568, built on February 24, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b06 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

[image: upside-down apple]

[image: horizontal sign]

I reported the bug but not sure if anyone else had this problem or what even causes it. Maybe it's an old problem? I guess I should downgrade?

Comment: I submitted to Android Studio people but they said it wasn't reproducible for them.